# Como pegar lista de todas as actions de todas as controllers, inclusive de Plugins?

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou tentando pegar todos os *methods/actions* de todas as *controllers* de minha aplicação CakePHP.

Acontece que não consigo trazer os métodos de todas as *controllers* e não entendo o motivo.

Tentei importar `App::import` e com `App::uses`, mas o `get_class_methods()` não retorna os *methods/actions* de todas.

Segue o que eu criei:

```
//Pega a lista de controllers da aplicação e adiciona num array;
$controllersApp = App::objects('controller');
//Varre o array de controllers da aplicação e adiciona cada item num array global
foreach($controllersApp as $c)
    {
        $temp_listControllers[] = $c;
    }
//Pega a lista de plugins
$plugins = App::objects('plugin');

//Varre o array de plugins
foreach($plugins as $plugin)
    {
        //Cria string para pegar lista de Controllers de cada Plugin: Plugin.controller
        $p = $plugin.'.controller';

        //Pega lista de controllers do Plugin corrente em $plugin
        $lista = App::objects($p);
        //Varre o array de controllers do Plugin corrente e adiciona cada item no array global
        foreach($lista as $l)
            {
                $temp_listControllers[] = $l;
            }
    }


foreach($temp_listControllers as $c)
    {
        //$r = str_replace("Controller", "", $c);
        $listControllers[] = $c;
    }    



foreach($listControllers as $controller)
    {

        $actions = get_class_methods($controller);
        echo "<hr /><h1>".$controller."</h1>";
        pr($actions);
    }
```

Estou fazendo algo errado? Existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente utilizar `Configure::listObjects();`

Eis aqui um [exemplo](http://bin.cakephp.org/view/835272537).

Comment: não tenho como testar esse método no momento, mas espero conseguir ajudar.

Comment: Então, estou usando uma versão 2.3.1 do CakePHP. Acontece que verifiquei na documentação do CakePHP e não encontrei em nenhuma versão o método getInstance da Class Configure. Dá o seguinte erro quando executo: Error: Call to undefined method Configure::getInstance()